# SignalR Not Receiving Messages AspNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am attempting to receive messages between two different identical webpages so that an asp:label on both of them can give information about what is currently being selected on each dropdownlist.

WebPage Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IHubProxy _hub;
    string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
    var connection = new HubConnection(url);
    _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("Hub");
    connection.Start().Wait();
    _hub.On("ReceiveMessage", x => CurrentInfo.Text = x);
}

protected void SaveStates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set the hubs URL for the connection
    string url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var connection = new HubConnection(url);

    var _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("Hub");

    connection.Start().Wait();

    _hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "Hello").Wait();
}
```

Hub Code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

[HubName("Hub")]
public class SignalHub : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(message);

        //TODO:
        //Respond to Messages
    }
}
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

What is currently happening?

At the moment the asp:label only updates for the certain page that the message was sent from. And not for both is there anything that I am doing wrong in the above code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I would really appreciate it if someone could give some demo code for it working in JS. All the examples I've found don't work

Comment: As far as I can see, you're creating two clients, not a client and one server. What tutorial did you read?

Comment: Oh sorry your quiet right I sent the wrong hub code. I'll edit it thanks :D

Comment: That is not the hub code... that's how you start the asp.net application. Missing startup class and the actual Hub.

Comment: Added that to. Sorry

Comment: Your client connection in `Page_Load` will be terminated/disposed as soon as the function exists, so they will only receive something if it's sent by the hub before they are disposed. This is why all sites I've seen has the client browser-side and not in the code behind...

Comment: You also have different base urls for the two clients.

Comment: The URLs being different didn't change anything in the program thanks for that however (Makes it look much cleaner) if you were to give some sample code for doing it in JS (Client Side) I'd be happy to accept your answer

Comment: There's plenty on the official ASP.NET SignalR website.

Comment: Do you have a link to something that works as I've been going through lots of pages for the day and haven't been able to find a working example

Comment: You should create your signalr client in js not in codebehind.

Comment: Do you have a sample code of it working in JS. All the examples I found aren't working. Ill accept that as the answer if given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your client like this:

reference signalr.js and chat.js in the html page you want to use signalr.

```
<script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

content of chat.js:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hub").build();

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score -1):

SendMessage method in SignalHub you use Clients.All.ReceiveMessage method
i think you should use  Clients.All.Send method (or SendAsync if you are using aspnet core)